# Como insertar el atributo checked en un input type=radio desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

estoy buscado pasar determinada informacion desde una pequeña base datos en JavaScript hacia una vista .ejs, la informacion se enviarla sin problema como segundo parametro en el res.render()

```
edit: (req, res) => {
    let userEditId = parseInt(req.params.idUser);
    userEditId = userEditId - 1;
    let userEdit = userBD[userEditId];
    res.render("userEdit", { userEdit: userEdit });
  },
```

Mi problema es que al realizar una validacion sobre la informacion recibida para un input type=radio, quisiera asignarle a el atributo "checked" al input que corresponda, en el caso de ser true. No logro encontrar la solucion ya que necesito que sea escalable para casos con multiples opciones para input type=checkbox tambien. Desde ya mil gracias por cualquier tipo de ayuda!!

```
<% if(userEdit.userTipe === "comprador"){%>
          <input
            class="loginBox-2"
            type="radio"
            name="userTipe"
            id="comprador"
            value="comprador"
          />
          <p class="option">Comprador</p>
          <input
            class="loginBox-2"
            type="radio"
            name="userTipe"
            id="vendedor"
            value="vendedor"
          />
          <p class="option">Vendedor</p>
          <%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, creo que lo único que has de hacer es poner el atributo **checked**. Por ejemplo, para el primer caso

```
<input
    class="loginBox-2"
    type="radio"
    name="userTipe"
    id="comprador"
    value="comprador"
    checked
/>
```

y si lo quieres condicional

```
<input
    class="loginBox-2"
    type="radio"
    name="userTipe"
    id="comprador"
    value="comprador"
    <% if(condicion){ %>checked<% } %>
/>
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! la segunda opcion con el condicional es la solucion escalable que estoy buscando, muchas gracias!!